# Julia: Simple BinDeps build.jl for installing dependency

Tags: dependencies, julia

I have created a Julia package which requires downloading a shared .so file for the local system. I am trying to use BinDeps to make the installation automatic.

Unfortunately, most of the examples I have found in other packages rely on built-in package managers to install their dependencies (apt, yum, etc.). I need to pull a specific .so file from a specific web link and install it.

How does one set up build.jl to install this simple dependency in Ubuntu?

I have tried:

```
using BinDeps
@BinDeps.setup
libsmilejl = library_dependency("smilejl", aliases=["libsmilejl", "libsmilejl.so"], os=:Unix)
provides(Binaries, URI("http://dl.bintray.com/tawheeler/generic/libsmilejl.so/libsmilejl.so"), libsmilejl, os = :Unix)
@BinDeps.install
```

Running the script results in "None of the selected providers can install dependency smilejl".

I have tried swapping Binaries with Sources, but get the same result. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't test on Linux, but on OSX this worked (or at least generated `deps.jl` and didn't throw any errors):

```
using BinDeps

@BinDeps.setup

libsmilejl = library_dependency("libsmilejl.so", os=:OSX)

provides(Binaries, 
    URI("http://dl.bintray.com/tawheeler/generic/libsmilejl.so/libsmilejl.so"),
    libsmilejl, os = :OSX)

@BinDeps.install [:libsmilejl => :libsm]
```

You might get more help if you open an issue on BinDeps.jl

Comment: Thank you. I tried running the same thing on my end with :Unix instead of :OSX and got the same error. What does the `:libsmilejl => :libsm` do?

Comment: When it generates the `deps.jl` file you include in your module, it creates an alias for your library. So I could refer to it as `libsm` instead of `libsmilejl`.

Comment: Thanks! I may try using download() to pull the file to a local folder and just add that folder to the path. Seem like a reasonable thing to do? I am having trouble moving it to usr/lib because I don't know how to get sudo rights.

Comment: Just fyi, running it does create the deps.jl file but that file just contains a function which explicitly throws an error